# Cheap PC build, USBTV007 device, no sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, usb, video

I have some old VHS tapes I would like to scan to disk files.  In looking around on eBay I found this cheap "EasyCap" usb stick that I can run cables from my VCR to that device and supposedly capture the viedo easily.

I tried VLC with the "Open Capture Device" option, and it showed a video0 device which I tried as the video input.  For the audio input it only says 1,0 and 1,2 - and I don't know what that means.  I tried selecting each one at a time and trying the capture.  Found out I had to set the video height and width in the "advanced options" for VLC - they apparently default to 0 which meant I had no video.

After making those 2 changes then I do get video fine.  I do not, however, get any audio.  I did some reading on the net and it would seem I should have another audio device show up when the stick is plugged in, but I don't get a new one.  Another item on the net said to check `dmesg` and see what it shows.  I don't know what to really look for but I found this:

```
[102956.889640] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using hci-pci
[102957.025363] usb 2-4: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 1 bulk endpoint 0x83 has invalid maxpacket 256
[102957.029230] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1b71, idProduct=3002
{102957.029239] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[102957.029244] usb 2-4: Product: usbtv007
[102957.029248] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: fushicai
[102957.029252] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 300000000002
[102957.079449] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[102957.087736] usbtv 2-4:1.0: Fushicai USBTV007 Video Grabber
[102957.087758] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbtv
[102967.749341] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[102978.761905] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[102978.897782] usb 1-3: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 1 bulk endpoint 0x83 has invalid maxpacket 256
[102978.901240] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1b71, idProduct=3002
[102978.901250] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[102978.901255] usb 1-3: Product: usbtv007
[102978.901259] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: fushicai
[102978.901263] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 300000000002
[102978.902194] usbtv 1-3:1.0: Fushicai USBTV007 Video Grabber
```

I do know the device is supposed to capture the sound as well.

If it might be of help, I built an extremely cheap PC using a Gigabyte motherboard and an AMD A6 7400K.  I know I had a little learning curve with it to begin with as it turned out I needed to set aside memory for video before I could even boot the installation DVD.

I believe it uses something like R% or some such "R" thing in there somewhere if that makes any difference.  I believe this series of APU is relatively new - some kind of new core - so maybe it's too new?  Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

If you need any more information from me please ask.  I'll do my best to try what you say and ask questions if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

I bought the same device and the sound works. I have disconnected my webcam to make sure it was the only device. I don't know if this could fix your problem.

I wanted to play record myself while playing games, but there's a 1 second lag in VLC because this thing streams at around 100MB/s. It doesn't compress the data.